# Application Insights not logging Questions and Answers from QNA Maker bot

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

When running the query, I was originally getting the Questions, Answers and Score of the questions asked to my bot. However, about 10 days ago it stopped logging.

I am still seeing activity in the application insights of the QNA Maker, but the "Custom Domains" where Questions, Answers and Score are logged is not showing up.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
traces 
| where customDimensions contains "question"
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
| extend score = tostring(customDimensions['Score'])
| project timestamp, question, answer, score
```

For some reason the suggested query in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base?tabs=v1) wasn't working for  me. But when I simplified it as above, it worked:

```
requests
| where url endswith "generateAnswer"
| project timestamp, id, url, resultCode, duration, performanceBucket
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)knowledgebases/"KbId"/generateAnswer"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| extend question = tostring(customDimensions['Question'])
| extend answer = tostring(customDimensions['Answer'])
| extend score = tostring(customDimensions['Score'])
| project timestamp, resultCode, duration, id, question, answer, score, performanceBucket,KbId
```